# Rails, pass an array through a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to push an array attribute in rails form using check_box_tag which looks like this:

```
= check_box_tag 'order[supplementals_ids][]', supplemental.id
```

Everything goes fine when submitting the form. I am examining the pushed params with a debugger just before creating an order. The output of params[:order] is

```
{"supplementals_ids"=>["2", "3"], "meal_id"=>"4"}
```

which looks fine. However, after creating the order, I get the following

```
supplementals_ids: nil
```

Any idea where is the problem? The allowed params in the orders controller look like this:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:meal_id, supplementals_ids: [])
```

What I suspect the problem is is that in my schema, the expected value of supplementals_ids is an integer.

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "meal_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.integer  "supplementals_ids"
  end
```

However, when serializing the attribute in my model, I get

> Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Fixnum. -- 0

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: are you trying to save array in `supplementals_ids` ?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to have  ["2", "3"] in it?

Comment: that's really bad. The best way is an association `has_many :supplements` in `Order` so you can save the supplements and get by `order.supplements`. (you might use a join model between order and supplement).

Comment: please check my answer, it will works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change column type in database using migration

```
class ChangeColumnSupplementalsIdsInOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column : supplementals_ids, :text
  end

  def down
    change_column : supplementals_ids, :integer
  end
end
```

Then add following code in model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize : supplementals_ids, Array
end
```

Then use `supplementals_ids` to save array in controller

```
order = Order.new  # supplementals_ids: []
order.stuff << params[:order][:supplementals_ids]
```

Note: Array of values **cannot** be saved in `integer` column `supplementals_ids`